# awk: divide odd columns by following even column

Tags: awk

I want to divide all the odd columns in a file by the  next even column, e.g. column1/column2, column3/column4,......, columnN/columnN+1

test1.txt

```
1 4 1 2 1 3    
1 2 4 2 3 9
```

desired output

```
0.25 0.5 0.333
0.5 2 0.333
```

I tried this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} { for (i=2; i<NF+2; i+=2) printf $(i-1)/i OFS; printf "\n"}'
```

but it doesn't work.

I would like to add that my actual files have a very large and variable (but always even) number of columns and I would like something that would work on all of them.

Comment: your desire input seems to have a typo, last field of line 2 should be 0.333

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2)printf "%f%s",$i/$(i+1),OFS;print "";}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
0.250000 0.500000 0.333333 
0.500000 2.000000 0.333333
```

You can adjust printing format to your needs see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html#Control-Letters) for more info.

Comment: To avoid adding the trailing blank: `awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)printf "%f%s",$(i-1)/$i,(i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' input.txt`

Comment: Thanks guys!!! I see I forgot a $ sign. I would have hoped my first post would have been better. But thanks for the correction and refinement.